# WIndows Server 2016 - Disk and Network columns are greyed on Task Manager

Tags: task-manager, windows-server-2016, disk-utility, performance-monitor

I need to enable columns **disk** and **network** on Server 2016 Standard.

[Screenshot Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv3Ee.png)

Answer (score 0):

As long as for today I've only found this option: you can use this

```
diskperf -y
```

from your command prompt to enable disk use in "Performance" tab at task manager.

Why these columns are visible -but disabled- at the "Processes" tab is, somehow, a mystery. Maybe the taskman.exe is the same on all recent Microsoft's operating systems and these columns get deactivated (but no hidden) at Server 2016.

Comment: Me too, is the only way ive found.